# How to Increase the size of root partition in command line

Tags: partitioning

My system shows me that my root partition is out of space, and because of it many applications are not working properly. I have installed it in VMware.
Now I want to increase the root partition size by adding virtual hard disk. But I  don't have any access to do it by Graphical mode. Please anyone help me out regarding this. Can anyone guide me to do step by step. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is command line a requirement? Why? Generally, you'd delete the existing partition, and then recreate it starting from the same block. Not sure it's the best idea, unless you actually know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can add storage space to a virtual machine by expanding its virtual hard disk.

When you expand a virtual hard disk, the added space is not immediately available to the virtual machine. To make the added space available, you must use a disk management tool to increase the size of the existing partition on the virtual hard disk to match the expanded size.

The disk management tool that you use depends on the virtual machine guest operating system. Many operating systems, including Windows Vista, Windows 7, and some versions of Linux, provide built-in disk management tools that can resize partitions. Third-party disk management tools are also available, such as Symantec/Norton PartitionMagic, EASEUS Partition Master, Acronis Disk Director, and the open-source tool GParted.

When you expand the size of a virtual hard disk, the sizes of partitions and file systems are not affected.
As an alternative to expanding a virtual hard disk, you can add a new virtual hard disk to the virtual machine. See Add a New Virtual Hard Disk to a Virtual Machine.

**Prerequisites**

- Power off the virtual machine.
- Verify that the virtual disk is not mapped or mounted. You cannot
  expand a virtual disk while it is mapped or mounted.
- Verify that the virtual machine has no snapshots.
- Verify that the virtual machine is not a linked clone or the parent
  of a linked clone.

**Procedure**

1. Select the virtual machine and select VM > Settings.
2. On the Hardware tab, select the virtual hard disk to expand.
3. Select Utilities > Expand.
4. Set the new maximum size for the virtual disk.
5. Select Expand.
6. Click OK after the disk expansion process is complete.

**What to do next**

Use a disk management tool to increase the disk partition size to match the expanded virtual disk size.

You can refer [to the vmware documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-73BEB4E6-A1B9-41F4-BA37-364C4B067AA8.html)

If this doesn't help, Can you please be more specific by providing exact details. (like VMWare version, host OS, guest OS, etc.)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/656997)

Comment: @Videonauth : Thank you for letting me know. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. My problem is exact like this. I work for a company where i have installed Centos 6.4 in VM machine and using it for some servers.Now the root ( / ) is almost full now. So now i want to add a new hard disk and increase the size of root from new one. And I have no GUI option do all this process in Graphical mode. Otherwise I would have done using Gparted. I should increase the root partition size using Command line mode only and I cannot lose my data at any cost. For one time I can restart my machine if its required. Please somebody help.

Comment: @PradeepKumar : Extending the volume in VMWare is done in 2 steps. First part (Assuming your Host OS is windows), you can follow the steps in **Procedure** mentioned above. Now coming to the second part, let the Guest OS know that there is an increase in disk space and adding it to the root file system. To do that, you can follow the steps mentioned at [fdisk for disk partition using command line](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42857/how-to-extend-centos-5-partition-on-vmware). If you still face any issue, feel free to post it.

Comment: @PradeepKumar : If you are curious to learn resizing drives in Linux, you can refer [Resizing Linux Drives](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/resize-vmware-linux-drives)